# Square of a binary matrix

Tags: combinatorics

I want to know how many binary matrices (with entries 0 or 1) $A=[a_{ij}]_3$ exist such that $b_{ij}\geq a_{ij}, \forall i,j=1,2,3$, where $B=A^2=[b_{ij}]_3$.

I have tried the same for the matrix of order 2 and came up with answer 13.

Comment: I do not understand. Are you counting number of ways to choose $A$ and $B$, subject to $b_{i,j}\ge a_{i,j}$? Or is $B$ a fixed matrix? Or is $B$ somehow determined by $A$? Also, what does the title of your question refer to; is $B$ supposed to be the square of $A$, as in $B=AA$?

Comment: $B$ is obviously determined by $A$. 

$B=A^2$

Comment: Can you provide your work for matrices of order 2. Did you just brute force through all $16$ combinations, or did you do something more elegant?

Comment: Brute force/ by hand

Comment: Brute force $333$