# Square Binary Matrices

Tags: matrices

Let $A=[a_{ij}]_3$ be a square matrix of order $3$ having entries $0$ or $1$.

Let $B=A^2=[b_{ij}]_3$.

When does the inequality $b_{ij}\geq a_{ij}, \forall i,j=1,2,3$ hold?

Comment: There are only $512$ such matrices. You could run through them (or program a machine to run through them), and pick out the ones that satisfy the inequalities.

Comment: There is no point in posting the same question twice (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4230563/square-of-a-binary-matrix). If you want to bump your question, you can just edit it. This should be closed as a duplicate.